# Is it possible to dynamically "move" HTML table cells up or down their respective columns?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-4, css-tables

I am using HTML, CSS with Bootstrap, and AngularJS for this.

Let's say I want to create a table that has two header columns, and the entry rows are divided into four columns. I will add different information from my object in these rows.

Let's pretend that the object we are showing information about is {{Banana}}. The header columns are:

"General information" | "Visual information".

In our first entry row, we want the following values:

"Origin:" | {{Banana.origin}} | "Shape": | {{Banana.shape}}

In our next entry row, we want the following values:

"Growth climate:" | {{Banana.growthClimate}} | "Color:" | {{Banana.color}}

Now let's say that this particular instance of banana has no shapespecified.
The table would still keep it's structure and just say "Shape" | *empty cell*.
What I would like, however, is to "move" the "Color:" | {{Banana.color}}" cells up to the row before it (that is if {{Banana.color}} has a value, if doesn't take corresponding two cells from the next row, etc.).

In other words, in this case I would like the table to look like this:

"General information" | "Visual information"
"Origin:" | {{Banana.origin}} | "Color": | {{Banana.color}}
"Growth climate" | {{Banana.growthClimate}}

Is this possible to achieve with HTML, CSS with Bootstrap, and AngularJS?

**EDIT:**

This code doesn't work:

```
`<thead>
     <tr>
         <th class="col-md">General information</th>
         <th class="col-md">Visual information</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td class="col-md">Origin</td>
         <td class="col-md">{{::Banana.origin}}</td>
         <td class="col-md">Shape</td>
         <td class="col-md">{{::Banana.shape}}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td class="col-md">Growth climate</td>
         <td class="col-md">{{::Banana.growthClimate}}</td>
         <td class="col-md">Color</td>
         <td class="col-md">{{::Banana.color}}</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>`
```

If {{Banana.shape}} is undefined here, it's cell will just be empty.

If I instead try:

```
`<td class="col-md" ng-show="Banana.shape">Shape</td>
<td class="col-md" ng-show="Banana.shape">{{::Banana.shape}}</td>`
```

or

```
`<td class="col-md" ng-if="Banana.shape">Shape</td>
<td class="col-md" ng-if="Banana.shape">{{::Banana.shape}}</td>`
```

Neither of these will work either, the row's cells would just be adjusted in size.

Comment: Just about anything is "possible". Can you post the code you've attempted and explain specifically what's not working?

Comment: This might be a good scenario to use css grid instead of bootstrap. Give it a try and post your code